# SIMD вызов _mm_cmpeq_pi8 портит память

Tags: c++, sse

Код собирается с target AVX2, при разборе "хвоста" решил использовать __m64, в результате после использования `_mm_cmpeq_pi8` переменная типа `double` приобретает значение `nan`, упрощённый пример кода:

```
__attribute__((target("avx2"),stdcall))
void test(std::vector<uint8_t> & v1, std::vector<uint8_t> & v2)
{
    double cmp = 0.0;
    // ...
    __m64 a1 = _mm_set_pi8(v1[i], v1[i + 1], v1[i + 2], v1[i + 3], ...);
    __m64 a2 = _mm_set_pi8(v2[i], v2[i + 1], v2[i + 2], v2[i + 3], ...);
    __m64 a3 = _mm_cmpeq_pi8(a1, a2);
    // после вызова _mm_cmpeq_pi8, cmp == nan
    uint32_t x = static_cast<uint32_t>(_mm_movemask_pi8(a3));
    cmp += ((x == 0xffffffffU) ? 0.1 : 0.0);

}
```

MMX инструкции не совместимы с AVX2? Вроде про это явно нигде не написано.
Вопрос в том как это можно пофиксить, кроме как отказавшись от использования __m64.

эксперименты проводились на камне `CoffeeLake`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При переходе от MMX к floating point необходимо выполнить команду `EMMS`, или `_mm_empty()` intrinsic.

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/emms